# Write title of selectet label after other element in same div via CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to set the title attribute of a label in a span before this label, both in the same div with CSS.

My HTML

```
<div class="building">
<label for="house">House:<span></span></label>
<div id="house">
<input type="radio" name="house" class="house" id="1" value="1" />
<label for="1" class="background for1" title="Title 1"></label>
<input type="radio" name="house" class="house" id="2" value="2" />
<label class="background for2" for="2" title="Title 2"></label>
<input type="radio" name="house" class="house" id="3" value="3" />
<label class="background for3" for="3" title="Title 3"></label>
</div>
</div>
```

target is this span
`<label for="house">House:<span></span></label>`

And the CSS

```
input[type="radio"]{display: none}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label{border:1px solid #FFF;box-sizing:border-box}
.for1{background:url(1.png)}
.for2{background:url(2.png)}
.for3{background:url(3.png)}
.background{cursor:pointer;background-size:contain;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;display:inline-block;width:33%;height:23px}
```

The empty label getting a clickable background picture an the checked is shown over a border around the picture.

Is it possible to set the title of the checked label to the empty span in the first label over CSS with before or after attribute.
Like

```
in div.building
write >label>span::after 
where div>input[type="radio"]:checked + label[title]:selected{content: attr(title)}
```

It's possible with javascript, I know, but CSS? I'm open for hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add content in blank label and show it only when it checked..., yes you can do it with  psuedo element :after(CSS2)/::after(CSS3):

first way you can do it like this in your stylesheet css:

```
input[id="1"]:checked +label[for="1"]::after{
    content:'title1';
}

input[id="2"]:checked +label[for="2"]::after{
    content:'title2';
}

input[id="3"]:checked +label[for="3"]::after{
    content:'title3';
}
```

for more simplier CSS use without iteration every radio, you can use "data attribute" in your HTML, you already did it in your label, just add prefixes 'data-' in every title in your label like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="house" class="house" id="1" value="1" />
<label class="background for1" for="1" data-title="Title 1"></label>

<input type="radio" name="house" class="house" id="2" value="2" />
<label class="background for2" for="2" data-title="Title 2"></label>

<input type="radio" name="house" class="house" id="3" value="3" />
<label class="background for3" for="3" data-title="Title 3"></label>
```

and in your try this shorter CSS code in your stylesheet:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked +label::after{
    content:attr(data-title);
}
```

i tested and it worked in my browser,

- I hope this help

Comment: Thank you ::after work but I want set an other span, see last edit of my question.

Comment: So you want "title 1","title 2",etc shows up not on beside radio button, but beside the "House:" text, inside empty <span> tag?

Comment: If that the case..,No, You Can't Combine/Target the <span> with the radio button,...Because the span is located on the parent/higher class than the radio button class. To target/combine two element as a selector in css, the targeted element must be located in the child/lower class...Or, at least they both are sibling or in same level of class tree.

Comment: Redesign and change your html design/structure first...maybe you can move and put the radio on parent top class or put down the span on lower/same class as radiobutton. so the span could be targeted from the radiobutton.

Comment: See my little example: https://jsfiddle.net/k88okf48/  ,I just remove house div and moving the span to the bottom, and it Works...i forgot to mention, the radio button must be in upper position even they both sibling.